# Tkinter - populate OptionMenu's options with list variables

Tags: types, tkinter, selector

So I have the following lists:

```
containers = []
lids = []
wicks = []
labels = []
misc = []
inventory = []

class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, desc, name, amount):
        self.desc = desc
        self.name = name
        self.amount = amount

a1 = [x.getName() for x in containers]
a2 = [x.getName() for x in lids]
a3 = [x.getName() for x in wicks]
a4 = [x.getName() for x in labels]
a5 = [x.getName() for x in misc]
items = [a1, a2, a3, a4, a5]
```

what I'm trying to do is populate a `type_selector`'s options with all the values from list `items`

Here's what I have based on what I found online so far:

```
add_amount_selector = StringVar()
type_selector = OptionMenu(mainframe, add_amount_selector, *items)
```

However what's happening is that all the values from items are merging together into one single option, ie:

```
{name1}{name2}{name3}
```

instead of:

```
{name1}
{name2}
{name3}
```

Not sure what the problem is here or how to change this.

Also is there a way to populate the option's menu with the list variables where it doesn't show the curly braces `{}`

**edit**

Ok I just did the following:

```
z = []
z.extend(a1)
z.extend(a2)
z.extend(a3)
z.extend(a4)
z.extend(a5)

items = z
```

and it seems to be working now.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are giving the option menu a list of lists. OptionMenus are not hierarchical. Each argument is expected to be a string, not a list. When you give it a list, the OptionMenu doesn't know how you want to format the list, so you get its own internal formatting.

You need to combine all of your lists into a single list before passing it to OptionMenu.